# ValueError when reshaping to 4 dim array for the Keras API

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, numpy, reshape

DL beginner here. I'm trying to implement LeNet using Keras and apply it on good ol' MNIST.

```
class LeNet:
@staticmethod
def build(height, width, depth, classes):
    model= Sequential()
    inputshape= (height,width, depth)

    if K.image_data_format()== 'channels_first':
        inputshape= (depth, height, width)

    #build model
    model.add(Conv2d(20, (5,5), padding= "same", input_shape= inputshape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    #replicate what's above again
    model.add(Conv2d(50, (5,5), padding= "same"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    #Fully Connected Layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    #softmax
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))


    return model
```

Then I load the dataset

```
print('[INFO] Accessing MNIST...')

dataset= loadmat('mnist-original.mat')
data=dataset['data']
```

Now I'm trying to reshape the data whose current shape is (784, 70000) by

```
data= data.reshape(data.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
```

But I get an error that says **ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 54880000 into shape (784,28,28,1)**

Where am I going wrong here? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to change the last line to `data= data.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)`